# Datagridview sorting a specific column

Tags: c#, sqlite

I have 2 datagridview's that i am trying to sort by one specific column.  What I am trying to do is when the program starts I want the DGV to automatically sort by one column by descending.  I have been searching and I cannot seem to find what I am looking for.

Here are images of what I am asking.  I want the journalID column to start at highest first and descend from there.

[image: What it starts as]

[image: What I am looking for]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                string connectionstring = @"Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Database1.sdf";
                SqlCeConnection connection = new SqlCeConnection(connectionstring);
                SqlCeCommand command = new SqlCeCommand(" SELECT * FROM journalTbl ORDER BY journalId DESC ;", connection);
                try
                {
                    SqlCeDataAdapter adapter = new SqlCeDataAdapter();
                    adapter.SelectCommand = command;
                    DataTable datatable = new DataTable();
                    adapter.Fill(datatable);
                    BindingSource bindingsource = new BindingSource();

                    bindingsource.DataSource = datatable;
                    dataGridView1.DataSource = bindingsource;
                    adapter.Update(datatable);
                }

                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);


}




        }
```

- Create a connection to the database and select the desired table via 
  a command

  - Include specific functions in the command (in this case ordering by journalId Desending)
  - Create a data adapter to allow communication between the dataset and the datasource
  - Create a datatable and fill via the data adapter
  - Create a binding source and assign it to the datatable
  - Set the datagridview datasource as the binding source.
  - Update the adapter

[Order By SQL](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp) - SQL Reference

[Order By clause C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb383982.aspx) MSDN Reference

**Please Note:** Order by will automatically order by Ascending. I am also using Sql Compact Edition.

Answer (score 0):

I will just add these lines on your *Form1_Load(...)* method.

```
DataGridViewColumn columnToSort = dataGridView1.Columns["ColumnNameToSortGoesHere"];
dataGridView1.Sort(columnToSort, ListSortDirection.Descending);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't should use Code Behind. You should study MVVM model and Linq library . You work will be better and will be cleaner.

In Model MVVM you solution for this problem is

In your ViewModel

```
private ObservableCollection<string> _listModelBinding;
public ObservableCollection<string> ListModelBinding
{
    get { return _listModelBinding; }
    set { _listModelBinding= value; RaisePropertyChanged("ListModelBinding"); }
}

public MainViewModel()
{

    ListModelBinding = ListModelBinding.OrderBy(x => x.ToString());

}
```

In your xaml simply create binding

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding ListModelBinding}" />
```

That's it.

You can use MVVM in your project using MVVM Light NuGet.